# What is the usage of the pseudo class :not()?

Tags: css, pseudo-class

I saw this pseudo class `:not()` being used in a source code of a **Youtube** video page, searching in the **MDN** I saw [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) explaining the pseudo class, but I couldn't understand why (*and in which case*) someone would use that.

Comment: Imagine that you have hundreds of different selectors, let's say classes. Imagine you want to select every div class except a single one. You could do `.foo, .bar, .baz .foobar .foobaz etc...{}`, with a humongous list, or you can just do `div:not(.foo) {}`.

Answer (score 2):

:not() use for exception in css.for example when you want to apply some styles in all div tags except one div with specific class you use not:()
like following code!

```css
div:not(.className){
  color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have many same `class` or `item` and you don't want to one specific `item` shouldn't be affected. It will be like this.

> If your html like this

```css
.contant-wrapper div:not(.new-heading){
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contant-wrapper">
  <div class="heading">bla bla bla</div>
  <div class="title">bla bla bla</div>
  <div class="card">bla bla bla</div>
  <div class="new-heading">bla bla bla</div>
</div>
```

> List item element

```css
ul li:not(:last-child){
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
ul li:not(:first-child){
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>bla bla bla</li>
  <li>bla bla bla</li>
  <li>bla bla bla</li>
  <li>bla bla bla</li>
  <li>bla bla bla</li>
</ul>
```